# Copying columns from two seperate tables via SQL

Tags: sql, database, magento

I am working with Magento and need to create a table in the database which will contain both the sku and stock values for a cron job which will be set up later.  These columns sit in seperate tables elsewhere in the database, if that makes sense.  I have tried to do this via SQL but for some reason I am getting a table with twice as many rows as I need.  The stock level rows end and then the sku rows begin.  I have googled this without any joy.  Please can anyone help?  I just want to pull across two columns from two seperate tables within the same database and have them sit inline with each other.

Comment: "the stock level rows emds and sku row begins" . Explan that , cannot undertand because a column can just have one field

Comment: getting extra rows means : CROSS JOIN(maybe)

Comment: I copied the column "qty" from product_stock_item table which gave me around 3500 rows. Then when I tried the same with "sku" from catalog_product_flat_1 the sku data began where the qty data ended (but within its own column) and gave me around 7000 rows instead of the 3500 I need.  So instead of having sku numbers and stock levels which line up with each other, I have stock levels without skus and skus without stock levels

Answer (score 0):

need a database design
eg
tableA fields a,b,c
tableZ fields x,y,z

Comment: The new table is called rc_sku with fields sku, qty ,product_id.   The first table to have data pulled from it is catalog_stock_item fields qty, product_id   
The next table is catalog_inventory_flat_1 field sku
The table names differ from my comment above, as I was working from memory...sorry and thanks for your input.

Comment: I dont find any primary key common to both table

Comment: Please excuse my stupidity, I'm not overly familiar with databases or SQL.  Could you explain what you mean?

Comment: this are two model tables . table student and table class . student(sid,sname,cid) and class(cid,cname) . now primary key sid and cid uniquely identify records and cid provides mapping fields for both table . if this is not done(no relation) then join of two table is cross join that is tableA count MULTIPlYED BY tableB count